# How can i get the average number from a range of text areas (user input)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, model-view-controller

I'm developing a form where users should input 12 numbers, one per month, each one in a row column. I need to get an average of that dynamic numbers below. The best way would be by using a 'Calculate' button users could click and view the result. How can i do it using JavaScript?

I looked for different options online but didn't found one that applies to this concrete concern. I attach the code for the rows and text areas:

```
   @*<h2><strong>Criação de Postos de Trabalho</strong></h2>
                    <br />

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Janeiro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="janeiro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Fevereiro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="fevereiro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Março</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="março"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Abril</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="abril"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Maio</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="maio"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Junho</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="junho"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Julho</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="julho"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Agosto</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="agosto"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Setembro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="setembro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Outubro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="outubro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Novembro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="novembro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Dezembro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="dezembro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <br />
                    <br />

                    Nº Médio de Postos de Trabalho dos 12 meses Precedentes:
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="medio"></textarea>





                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>*@
```

For example, if user inputs "1" in each month, i would like them to see "1" when they click the 'Calculate' button. Just need to get an average for the 12 entered fields.

Comment: So what is the problem? How to get the values entered into the fields? How to sum them up and calculate the average?

Comment: What is your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this Example will help you out.
HTML Code below

```
<form>
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
        <input class="input-no" type="number" name="">
    </form>
    <div>
        <button>Average</button>
        <input type="number" class="avg" name="">
    </div>
```

Jquery code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var totAvg = 0;
    $('button').click(function(){
        for(var i=0;i<12;i++){
            totAvg = totAvg + parseInt($('form').children('input').eq(i).val(),10);
        }
        $('.avg').val(totAvg/12);
        totAvg = 0;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer :

First of all you don't need textearea for a number inputs, choose input tag of type number.
Next : you select all the textareas and loop on this "collection"
then you check id the input is a number and add it to a count variable
at the end you divide the result by 12 and put it in the media textearea.

```js
  document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function(){
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"); 
 var result = 0;
 if(inputs){
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
   if(inputs[i].getAttribute("id") != "medio"){
    var entry = parseInt(inputs[i].value);
    if(!isNaN(entry)){
     result+= entry;
    }
   }
  }

 }
  document.getElementById("medio").value = (result / 12).toFixed(2);; 
});
```

```html
<h2><strong>Criação de Postos de Trabalho</strong></h2>
                    <br />

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Janeiro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="janeiro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Fevereiro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="fevereiro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Março</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="março"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Abril</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="abril"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Maio</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="maio"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Junho</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="junho"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Julho</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="julho"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Agosto</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="agosto"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Setembro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="setembro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Outubro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="outubro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Novembro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="novembro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment">Dezembro</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="10" id="dezembro"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <br />
                    <br />
     <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
                         <br />
                    <br />
                    Nº Médio de Postos de Trabalho dos 12 meses Precedentes:
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="medio"></textarea>





                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```